# Update error rails (stack level too deep)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm facing a error in rails while updanting a attribute `accepted`.
`accepted` is a `boolean` type coloumn.

This is the code:

```
 def response
if params[:response]
  @invite = Invite.find_by(invited: '2')
  @invite.update(accepted: params[:response])
  render nothing: true
end
end
```

The trace (sorry for image):

[image]
The error is **Stack level is too deep**

Comment: The code you posted looks correct. Post the entire stacktrace, including the error and the error line, and the code gist that generated that error.

Comment: There might be a problem in one of your callbacks, but as @SimoneCarletti has already said we cannot be certain unless we see the stack trace. You can copy it from your rails server logs and paste it here.

Comment: @Igor, any update? Did changing the action name solve the problem? And please update your post with some more information.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed ...edited with the trace...the error only show this message, witthout lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess when you are calling `update` action and passing `params[:response]`, somehow it's invoking `response` action and falling into an infinite loop, which is raising 'stack level too deep' error.

Change `response` to `update_response` or something else to fix the problem.

```
def update_response
  if params[:response]
    @invite = Invite.find_by(invited: '2')
    @invite.update(accepted: params[:response])
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

*I'll update this answer as soon as I find any explanation.*